# How to get a substring from the results of a Formal class?

Tags: r

Maybe a simple question but here's a reproducible example (it happens with any similar example for me though):

```
library(BayesFactor)
tab <- as.table(cbind(Office=c(18,31),Phone=c(5,7)))
ctb <- contingencyTableBF(tab,sampleType = "poisson")
ctb
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 0.4968786 ±0%

Against denominator:
  Null, independence, a = 1 
---
Bayes factor type: BFcontingencyTable, poisson

ctb@bayesFactor$bf
[1] -0.6994095
```

If you type `str(ctb)` it returns "Formal class" and lists the elements of the class.

I'm trying to just extract the Bayes factor of 0.4968786 from the text programmatically. When I call from the class using `@bayesFactor$bf` it gives me a different number (-0.699), and I'm not even sure it makes sense that Bayes factors can be negative?

Am I doing something wrong, and if so, what is the proper way (or any way) to gather that number 0.4969 from the results? Thanks for your help

Comment: I found one way `as.data.frame(ctb)$bf` but what I'm really looking for is how to convert the results of a formal class to string in general, and then take a substring that isolates the numbers in question.

Comment: I have tried `as.character(ctb)` for example to no avail.